# Shell script to partition an SD card

Tags: bash, shell-script, partition, sd-card, sfdisk

I am quite new to Unix/Linux. I am trying to write a bash script which will format and partition an SD card to have the exact layout with 7 partitions as shown below.

I've had a look at `sfdisk`, but unfortunately not sure where to start.

Aren't only four primary partitions allowed also? I'd appreciate any help.

```
    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
    /dev/mmcblk1p1             129         640       16384   c Win95 FAT32 (LBA)
    /dev/mmcblk1p2             641       15360      471040  83 Linux
    /dev/mmcblk1p3           15361       30080      471040  83 Linux
    /dev/mmcblk1p4           30081       95744     2101248   f Win95 Ext'd (LBA)
    /dev/mmcblk1p5           30337       94208     2043904  83 Linux
    /dev/mmcblk1p6           94337       94976       20480  83 Linux
    /dev/mmcblk1p7           95105       95744       20480  83 Linux
```

Comment: this may help you a bit https://stackpointer.io/unix/linux-script-to-partition-disk/632/

Comment: there are only 4 primary partitions in that table

Comment: @jsotola Which ones?

Comment: look at the starting and ending blocks of each of the partitions .... what do you see?

Comment: What jsotola is saying is that `/dev/mmcblk1p4` is an extended partition and the ones below it are logical partitions. It is true that only 4 primary partitions are allowed (in MBR partitioning), but the scheme you have outlined includes an extended partition which allows extra.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski where is the partition table for the extended partition stored?